# ADF excel copy activity first row data

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way in (I know you can do this in data bricks) to specify the first row of data in a source excel file?

I have a bunch of excels and they start at A6 but this cannot be a range as I will never know the end and width.

Can you use the dynamic content [image]

The issue I also face is there is a few rows of data in 1-5 but I dont need it I just want to skip to a6 where the columns start

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out

you can use the range example A6 and the tick the first row
[image]

This will start your data from there